# Calling functions from an ASP.NET code file with javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax

I have a JavaScript-based timeline which needs to use data from an SQL server. The queries and the JSON conversions have been worked out in the form of C#.NET functions within a code file related to an .aspx page.

So for a complete newbie to ASP.NET, how do you set up a function call like this from JavaScript?

I would love it if someone had some simple example code I could learn/get some pointers from.

Edit: I am using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do it with jQuery

```
$.getJSON("MyAction" { Data: somedata}, function(data) {
    // do stuff on callback
});
```

Comment: -1: That works how well for calling arbitrary methods in server-side C# code from the client-side JavaScript?

Comment: cc0 asked for the client script implementation John, thanks chief.

Comment: Thank you either way, that helps