# ASP.NET event that triggers both a javascript function then a c# function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0

I would like to accomplish an on click event to preform 2 functions sequentially

```
< onclick=" JavaScriptFunction() , C#ServerSideFunction()">
```

how would I go about this. I have found an example of how to do 2 javascript functions sequentially but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it call a js function, and have that function call the js function you want first, and then call the C# function.

You can call a C# function from js using AJAX.  Here's an example post about that:

[Calling functions from an ASP.NET code file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322977/calling-functions-from-an-asp-net-code-file-with-javascript)

And here's a whole blog post about calling C# from js:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

What you'll essentially need to do is call a javascript function (which performs your client-side activities) which when finished makes your postback to the server.

In order for javascript to perform the postback you would use:

```
__doPostBack('<%=btnPlaceHolder.UniqueID %>', '')
```

as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957442/how-to-postback-server-by-javascript-asp-net).